# I' trying to add a backGround img using React, but something is wrong whith the path

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

This is the state to style the html tag

```
  const [favStyleButton, setFavStyleButton] = useState({
    width: "100px",
    height: " 100px",
    backgroundImage: "url('../media/pokeball.png')",
    backgroundSize: "contain",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    border: "none",
  });
```

Using css works

```
.pokemon .tittle .btn-fav button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("../media/pokeball.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

I'm in the folder pokemon and the file pokemon.js, and i'm trying the get the img
from the folder media and the img pokeball.png
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afrk8.jpg)

I took a image from internet and it works, but using a img from my project, don't work.
Surely the error is on the path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the image first

```
import bgImg from '../media/pokeball.png';
```

then use bgImg variable

```
const [favStyleButton, setFavStyleButton] = useState({
    width: "100px",
    height: " 100px",
    backgroundImage: `url(${bgImg})`,
    backgroundSize: "contain",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    border: "none",
  });
```